# What does "be buggered sideways" mean?

Tags: meaning, offensive-language

From the movie *"Atomic Blonde"*

The main character, Lorraine, is briefed by her bosses about a secret document, the list, which can expand the Cold War for another 40 years, if Russians have it.

> If the Russians get that list, we're all buggered sideways.

I suppose it's some kind of British slang, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Especially the "sideways" part.

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bugger%20me%20sideways  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugger#Verb

Comment: @Spagirl: I disagree. Kris's link gives no explanation of why Brits often say things like *Fuck me sideways with a bargepole!*, but that type of whimsical flourish rarely occurs with *Bugger me!* (= *I'm astonished!*). In any case, OP's context is *We're buggered / fucked* (= *We're in a very bad situation*, which is a somewhat different usage rarely involving anything being inserted sideways.

Comment: @Spagirl It doesn't make for an answer because an asker is expected to do some background research like looking up a dictionary or just Google the expression before posting. I was only being helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Americans rarely use ***bugger*** anyway, so OP's cited example is very definitely a *British* slang usage. But the BrE "standard" exclamation is [*Fuck me sideways!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fuck%20me%20sideways%22) (2,270 hits in Google Books) rather than [*Bugger me sideways!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bugger%20me%20sideways%22) (441 hits).

But both versions involving "sideways" are normally used to express *surprise*, rather than to convey the negativity of some outcome or condition. It's also worth noting 270 written instances of [*Fuck me sideways **with** XXXX*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fuck%20me%20sideways%20with%22), where *XXXX* is some almost randomly chosen object such as *a rusty poker, my uncle's marrow, a chainsaw, a wooden stake* (that's just the first four nouns after ***with*** in my search; they're all extreme examples of things you certainly wouldn't want used as a "dildo" in penetrative sex, regardless of the orientation or orifice! :). You might think extensions like that *emphasise* the surprise, but in practice I'd say their main purpose is to inject a note of levity (and reassurance that the unexpected situation isn't necessarily being perceived as a bad thing).

Regardless of whether the intention is to convey surprise or negativity, most speakers recognise the ***fuck*** versions as (potentially, at least) more offensive than those based on ***bugger***. I therefore suspect that quirky extensions such as *... sideways with a red-hot poker* occur more often with ***fuck***, simply because they distract attention from the taboo word itself (tending to amplifying the substance of the assertion by focusing on whimsy rather than profanity).

---

In short, I think ***sideways*** in OP's example is a relatively uncommon "flourish" for the context. Personally, I'd usually use the more highly-charged ***fucked***, but if I wanted to distract attention from that I might add something like [*If it does, we'll all be **fucked six ways from Sunday***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fucked%20six%20ways%20from%20Sunday%22) (that's 190 hits in Google Books).

Comment: Look here: http://www.lostinthepond.com/2013/09/4-british-swear-words-that-are-slowly.html

Comment: @Kris: I haven't seen *Atomic Blond*, but IMDB tells me that it's about an undercover MI6 agent (British Secret Service). On checking, I see the director David Leitch and screenwriter Kurt Johnstad are both American, so they probably wouldn't realise that ***sideways*** is somewhat "non-idiomatic" in the exact cited context. Not that they'd necessarily care - it sounds "quirkily British" to the AmE ear (just plain "quirky" to my BrE ear), and I've no doubt they're more concerned with "impressions" rather than true authenticity. Idiomatic swearing is quite precise in some respects, I think.

Comment: My comment wasn't about Atomic Blond at all but about *bugger* in AmE.

Comment: @Kris: Sure. And *my* point was that although we might expect idiomatic BrE profanity from the central character in the movie (because she's a British Secret Service operative), we should bear in mind that the writer and director are both American. So people shouldn't assume Lorraine's vernacular accurately reflects BrE. The main thrust of my answer is to point out that I at least think that *We're buggered sideways* is a clumsy/non-idiomatic attempt to "Briticize" what would more naturally be expressed as *We're [totally] fucked* on both sides of the pond.